# Java: How to put the value of a user defined attribute into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, class

For example, if this is my class...

```
 public class Person {
   private double height; //Height in inches

   //constructors
   public Person(double newHeight) {height = newHeight;}
   public Person() {}

   //Getter
   public double getHeight() {return height;}

   //Setter
   public void setHeight(double newHeight) {height = newHeight;}

  }
```

and then this is my driver...

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 class Myclass {
   public static void main{String[] args) {

   String userInput;
   int arraylen;

   Person bob = new Person ();
   double[] myarray;

   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many heights do you have
   to list?");
   arraylen = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

   myarray = new double[arraylen];

   for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++) {

   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the next height?");
   bob.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(userInput));
   // I need something here to put that attribute value into the array.
   }
  }
 }
```

So at this point I have a value in the height attribute and I need to figure out how to move that into an array. I'm sure putting user input into an attribute to just then move it to an array probably isn't the best way to do this, but it's for school, so it's what I need to figure out. Please share any suggestions of better ways to do it though. However, I'm mainly concerned with how to do it like this.

Comment: `myarray[i]=Double.parseDouble(userInput);` ? or `myarray[i] = bob.getHeight();` ?

Comment: are you intentionally setting `bob`'s height each time in the loop?

Comment: @khelwood I agree with your answer. But I'm new here, so please forgive my ignorance. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @aguibert yes I am intentionally setting the height.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, the second one marry[i] = bob.getHeight(); worked! I was thinking something along that line, but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to want to do, setting the height of `bob` to a value, and then setting the entry in an array to the height of `bob`, can be done by adding the line:

```
myarray[i] = bob.getHeight();
```

to the end of your `for` loop.